# Optimal way to transfer values from a Map<K, V<List>> to a Map<otherKey, otherValue<List>>

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, collections, java-stream

Heres what i got to work with:
`Map<Faction, List<Resource>>`

- Faction is the enum String value of a player faction (e.g "rr" for team red, "bb" for team blue)
- Resources is String enum value of a Resource e.g "Wool", "Lumber"

So the list looks like this right now:

```
("rr", "wool")
("rr", "wool")
("rr", "lumber")
("bb", "wool")
```

---

So my goal is to have a `Map<Resource, Integer>`

- where Resource is String name of a Resource from an enum
- Integer represents the amount of Resource Cards

Example of target contained values: `("Wool", 4), ("Grain", 3), ("Lumber", 2)`

---

So I'm trying to do this (in pseudocode):

- extract all resources belonging to `Faction` "rr" and put them into a map `<Resources, Integer>` where each resource type should be represented once and `Integer` represents the sum of the amount of `Resource` cards
  --> repeat this step for 3 more player `Faction`

---

I've played around with streams and foreach loops but have produced no valuable code yet because I struggle yet in the conception phase.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution or you have a solution but want a better one? If you have a solution, can you post it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that actual input data in `Map<Faction, List<Resource>>` look like:

```
{rr=[wool, wool, lumber], bb=[lumber, wool, grain]}
```

Assuming that appropriate enums are used for `Resource` and `Faction`, the map of resources to their amount can be retrieved using `flatMap` for the values in the input map:

```java
Map<Faction, List<Resource>> input; // some input data

Map<Resource, Integer> result = input
    .values() // Collection<List<Resource>>
    .stream() // Stream<List<Resource>>
    .flatMap(List::stream) // Stream<Resource>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        resource -> resource,
        LinkedHashMap::new, // optional map supplier to keep insertion order
        Collectors.summingInt(resource -> 1)
    ));
```

or `Collectors.toMap` may be applied:

```java
...
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        resource -> resource,
        resource -> 1,
        Integer::sum,      // merge function to summarize amounts
        LinkedHashMap::new // optional map supplier to keep insertion order
    ));
```